# How can I use data from POST request to manipulate the DOM using a script.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

After making a post request I want to update my database and then use an array to update the DOM. Unfortunately, I do not know how to send that data to my script.js file.

Here is what I have so far

**SERVER**

```
    let expenseAmount = req.body.expenseAmount;
    let expenseType = req.body.expenseType;

    console.log(expenseAmount, expenseType);

    const currentExpense = new expense({
        amount: expenseAmount,
        reason: expenseType,
    })

    expense.insertMany(currentExpense, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log("successfully saved")
        }
    })

    expense.find({}, function (err, expenses) {
        expenseArr = expenses;
    })

})
```

**SCRIPT**

```
const myButton = document.querySelector(".BUTTON")

transferButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    function fetchData() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(console.log(data))
    }
    fetchData();
})
```

How can I access the data from the database and then use it to manipulate the DOM

Comment: what is the result of logging data in SCRIPT?

Comment: Change `fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(console.log(data))` to `fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data from your fetch after the promise is resolved.

You are on the correct track though you have your `then()` setup incorrectly. You need to setup a function to get that data. [then reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

To fix your then error change to this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(data => console.log(data))
```

That returns the response from the fetch, which still doesn't provide you with your data, though the data is in the response. This second block describes what you need to do if your request contains a `JSON` payload

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Here is a url for using fetch for your reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I am sorry if I am misunderstanding but are you saying I should replace the first block of code with the second?

Comment: I had another question regarding the server-side data how would I send the JSON object to the script.js file, like how do I specify what must be fetched. Sorry for the questions, I have just started learnign.

Comment: You will need to look at the code or documentation of the server you are requesting data from. It will let you know how it is being sent back to the client. I have updated my answer to add some clarity on the sections

Comment: thank you so much for your help that clarifies a lot.